# The Crown Estate API data into QGIS

Tags: qgis, api

I am trying to pull this data from https://www.thecrownestate.co.uk/api/energy-map/wind-farm-data into QGIS.

This is a real-time data coming from the interactive map: https://www.thecrownestate.co.uk/en-gb/what-we-do/asset-map/#tab-2

As far as I understand, the API is in a non-standard GeoJSON format. I tried to connect the database as a HTTPS protocol but did not work. Obviously, due to the non-standard structure, it was not that easy to use HTTPS connection only. How can I find a similar Python script to connect this API into QGIS?

Comment: That doesn't look like any standard format, you are going to need a custom script to fix it up.

Comment: Thank you. Then this is an issue as I am not good at Python. Do you know of any similar in any of the posts script that I can modify? I tried to some research but could not find any. Thanks

Comment: You can hire programmers for not much money

Comment: If it's "non-standard GeoJSON", it's just JSON, not GeoJSON.

Answer (score 1):

The Crown Estate has an Open Data Catalogue
https://opendata-thecrownestate.opendata.arcgis.com/

They use the ArcGIS REST API

> `https://services2.arcgis.com/PZklK9Q45mfMFuZs/arcgis/rest/services/`

in QGIS (3.26)
[image]

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. I have found and connected this to Qgis, already but this service does not contain dynamic series in the link I have shared. They only share static content as you show in the snapshot. I think I will use a Python script to download the data as json in local drive, convert into geojson and load in Qgis for temporal analysis.