Extract shapefiles from this Esri map using QGIS
I'm trying to get this spatial data as shapefiles:
https://thecrownestate.maps.arcgis.com/apps/webappviewer/index.html?id=b7f375021ea845fcabd46f83f1d48f0b
However I can't find out how to download it.
Is there a way to extract the data in QGIS?

In QGIS
Use https://services2.arcgis.com/PZklK9Q45mfMFuZs/arcgis/rest/services/
In QGIS Browser use ArcGIS REST services and add the url as a new connection
Load the WindCable_EngWalNI_TheCrownEstate (FeatureServer) and Wind sites
Then right click on the layer then you can Export as Shapefile 'Save Features As'


As a note: the link to the REST services  URL to use comes from the webmap source code/inspection

It was another QGIS question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/442726/the-crown-estate-api-data-into-qgis but this question explicitly requests shapefile

Looks like there is a way to find the open data sources to download if you want the data locally.
Looking at the link you shared, if you ask for more details on a given feature, it will provide you with a link to the related open data.

The main page is located here: https://opendata-thecrownestate.opendata.arcgis.com/search?collection=Dataset
From that link, if you explore a bit, you will see that the datasets are made available and you can download them in the desired format (Shapefile for instance)

